# Where do Jedi keep confiscated Sith artifacts?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

I was looking into the Jedi archive. I was wondering in which room in the Jedi archive do they keep Sith artifacts such as Sith holocrons, talismans, etc?

Comment: Under their temple on Coruscant.

Comment: They have a private vault in a Swiss bank.

Comment: Sell them off to the Jawas for cash.

Comment: Valorum is right - according to Tarkin novel, the Jedi temple is literally built on an ancient Sith site

Comment: I always vaguely assumed that they destroyed items like that. What would the point be in keeping them around?

Comment: Yoda sleeps with them under his bed.

Comment: Gringotts probably

Answer (score 1):

The Jedi had a vault inside their library on Coruscant in the temple, the Audible book "Dooku, Jedi Lost" goes into some detail about it. They usually keep them their to study  or make sure that they do not fall back into Sith hands. As for not destroying them, that is generally unpreferable as destroying the artifact usually releases some sort of shockwave/explosion that can kill anyone immediately in the vicinity.

Comment: Some book quotes would improve this answer greatly.

Comment: What stops them from throwing artifacts in a nearby star?

Comment: @Harabeck - they tried that with the Sun Crusher in the Jedi Academy book trilogy; Kyp Durron (with a little help from the spirit of Exxar Kun) simpley levitated it back out and into service again. At least that's how I remember it - I don't have the books any more so can't check right now, but the Sun Crusher was definitely retrieved from within a star.

Comment: @Spratty The Sun Crusher is not a Sith artifact. It survived because of its special armor. Nothing Sithy about it.

Comment: @Harabeck - Yes, I knew the Sun Crusher was completely un-Sithy (I love "Sithy" by the way; I'm claiming that one as my own), I was just pointing out that anything that could somehow survive being dropped into a star (and I have no idea how tough some Sith artifacts might be) could be resurrected.